# Making an "Add Tab" button on jQuery UI tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a jQuery UI tab control in my web page, and i want to make an "Add Tab" button having the same look than the tab titles (and located in the "tab bar", with other tab titles). I added an item in the list, with a specific class allowing me to make it float on the right. But I cannot remove the default action added by jQuery (on click, open related tab), which leads to an error, because the tab doesn't exist.

I tried several methods :

- Disabling the tab makes it fade on the screen (removing the css I want)
- Using `unbind` does not remove the onClick listener.
- Setting another onClick listener does not work either, as it is simply ignored...

I'm losing my mind on this. Anyone can help me stay sane ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`select`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#event-select) event and catch the event when clicked on your tab. In there you could make a new tab and give that focus.

Answer (score 1):

As Jerone pointed out, the `select` event is your friend.

Set the url of your 'Add' tab to "#Add" (Or some other value that can be used to uniquely identify that tab) 
Inside the event handler, check the value of ui.tab.hash, to check if this hash value is present and , if so, create the new tab, select it, and return 'false'. If the hash value doesn't match you magic value, then return 'true', to let the tab selection process continue as normal.